# NSView events randomly stop after several seconds when having a child window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a main window with main NSView handling its events. It works fine.

However, once I add a transparent child window, events stop being sent randomly after about 5 seconds, until I move the mouse. For example, if I scroll, it works fine for about 5 seconds, then the `scrollWheel` event is simply not triggered, until I move the mouse a bit.

(I need the transparent child window to display native elements on top of the Metal view).

Here's how I add the child window:

```
////
 CGRect wRect = main_window.frame;
 NSView *contentView  = main_window.contentView;
 CGRect cRect = contentView.frame;

 CGRect rect = CGRectMake(wRect.origin.x, wRect.origin.y, cRect.size.width, cRect.size.height);
 NSWindow *overlayWindow = [[NSWindow alloc]initWithContentRect:rect
                                                      styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                                        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                          defer:NO];
overlayWindow.backgroundColor = [[NSColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0];
[overlayWindow setOpaque:YES];


child_view = [[MyView2 alloc] init];
overlayWindow.contentView = child_view;

[main_window addChildWindow:overlayWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
///////////

[main_window center];
[main_window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

If I remove the `addChildWindow` call, events work fine again.

Also it's quite interesting that if I don't set the child window's background to transparent via `overlayWindow.backgroundColor = [[NSColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0];`, no events are sent to the main window.

**update**

This applies only to mouse events (scroll, click). Keyboard events work fine.

**update 2**

I've noticed that all events stop immediately after a `mouseExited` event, and I have to move the cursor around randomly until I get a `mouseEntered` event, then the scrolling works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a child view to the main view, instead of an entire new window:

```
[contentView addSubview:child_view];
```

I don't know what the issue with the child window was, could be a bug with transparent child windows.